# How to use a veriable immediatly before an underscore in an expect script?

Tags: unix, tcl, expect

I'm trying to use one variable to generate a second variable.
However, it's treating the underscore after the variable as part of the variable.
How do i force it to recognize the variable in this situation?

**Error**

```
can't read "v_host_": no such variable
    while executing
"set v_log_file "/some/loc/dir_$v_host_*/file.log""
    (file "./test.exp" line 3)
```

**Expect Script:**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
...
set v_host [lindex $argv 0]
set v_log_file "/some/loc/dir_$v_host_*/file.log"
```

**Update**: Copied the correct error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your file you *actually* say this:

```
set v_log_file "/some/log/dir_"$v_host"_*/file.log"
```

This isn't legal Tcl code. If you are using double quotes, you need to put them around the whole word; this is *different* to bash. Instead, you do this:

```
set v_log_file "/some/log/dir_${v_host}_*/file.log"
```

That is, putting braces around the name of the variable to distinguish it from the rest of the string. Or you can build the string piecemeal with `append`, whose first argument is a variable name (same as with `set`):

```
set v_log_file "/some/log/dir_"
append v_log_file $v_host
append v_log_file "_*/file.log"
```

Both approaches are valid. (I prefer the first of the two working approaches, but YMMV.)

Comment: You might want to clarify that "the first" in your last sentence refers to using braces, not to the first line you mention (which is illegal).

Comment: Thanks, using the curly braces will clean up my script a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried concat and join, but it kept adding whitespace for some reason.

I ended up using append instead and got the expected result from that.

**Using Append:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
...
set v_host [lindex $argv 0]
set v_log_file "/some/loc/dir_"
append v_log_file "$v_host" "_*/file.log"
```

**Result:**

```
/some/loc/dir_hostname_*/file.log
```

**Updated**
Corrected typo that Peter Lewerin caught.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm asking because the first argument to `append` is supposed to be a variable name (the other arguments are appended to the value of the variable, e.g. `append v_log_file $v_host _*/file.log`). `set v_log_file "/some/loc/dir_${v_host}_*/file.log"` is simpler.

Comment: Using curly braces didn't work (one of the first things i tried)